# Clearing a cookie when using Twisted and Python

Tags: python, cookies, twisted

I am using twisted to fetch a page.  For every callback to get a page....is the cookie reset?  If not, how do I reset a cookie for every callback?  Below is an example...I need a separate cookie for each reqest.

```
client.getPage(iUrl,headers,method='GET',cookies=  {}).addCallback(self.processPage,iUrl).addErrback(self.printError,iUrl)
client.getPage(iUrl,headers,method='GET',cookies=   {}).addCallback(self.processPage,iUrl).addErrback(self.printError,iUrl)
client.getPage(iUrl,headers,method='GET',cookies= {}).addCallback(self.processPage,iUrl).addErrback(self.printError,iUrl)
client.getPage(iUrl,headers,method='GET',cookies= {}).addCallback(self.processPage,iUrl).addErrback(self.printError,iUrl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  `{}` creates a new dictionary each time it is evaluated.  Each of the 4 calls in your example uses a separate cookies dictionary.  No cookies are shared between the requests.